# Nginx gets all access logs from a single useragent

Tags: nginx

On my nginx web server , serving link redirects for mobile devices I am getting most users having same useragent string as 
"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0"

Out of 400k links 355k links have the same useragent. All the links are actually accessed on mobile devices

What would cause this ?

Comment: Lots of reason. I would also take a look at the associated up-addresses as sometimes you find that monitoring and testing skews such results

Comment: I assumed the same , but all these IP addresses are from different locations